# MVC3 -- Adding additional items to List<> with Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model that looks like this:

```
HomeViewModel hvm = new HomeViewModel();
hvm.Applicant = new Person();
hvm.Applicant.Residences = new List<Residence>();
hvm.Applicant.Residences.Add(new Residence() { Type = "Current" });
```

In my .cshtml page, I have:

```
<label>Street # *:</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Applicant.Residences[0].StreetNumber)
```

And so on and so forth for my properties in my Residence model.  However, I want the user to be able to add multiple residences(previous, secondary, other, etc).  I can add the necessary form fields via jquery, however, since the model doesn't know about the new list items, I get an error about null objects.  The front end may be adding numerous residences via jquery.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly complex topic.  Check out the blog series starting with http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dynamic-form

View demo here: http://sroucheray.org/blog/jquery-dynamic-form/